# Protocol Buffer error C2059 under VS2008

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Now I have one message defined in protocol buffer

```
message Test
{
    enum OperationFlag
    {
        ADD = 0;
        DELETE = 1;
    }
    optional OperationFlag flag = 1;
}
```

After complied with `protoc`(version 2.5.0), the header file will be generated. However there is one error `syntax error : 'constant'` for the following line

```
static const OperationFlag DELETE = Test_OperationFlag_DELETE;
```

After investigation, I find the `DELETE` has already been declaration in the `WinNT.h`

```
#define DELETE  (0x00010000L)
```

It seems that `DELETE` can not be declared in protocol buffer? Am I right? or is there any other key words can not be used in protocol buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `DELETE` from WinNT.h, you can undefine it with `#undef`:

```
#include "windows.h"
#undef DELETE
....
static const OperationFlag DELETE = Test_OperationFlag_DELETE;
```